# How do I identify and display an embedded URL parameter using HTML?

Tags: html, url-parameters, godaddy-api

Using a redirect URL from Cognito Forms, I'm able to embed a parameter in the URL.  Works great, I'm a big Cognito Forms fan!  The URL looks like this:  http://mywebsite.com/results?Score=x  where x is equal to any whole number from 0 to 100.  So when the page loads as a result of the redirect URL it might be http://mywebsite.com/results?Score=48

I simply want to display the score on my page, in this case x = 48.  I'm using a GoDaddy Website builder which allows me to insert a custom HTML code section on a page, but I haven't been able to figure out the right code to make the actual Score display.  I simply want to show on the page ...  **Score = 48** ... or whatever value is is embedded in the URL.

Seems like it shouldn't be hard, but I haven't been able to accomplish it.  GoDaddy isn't able to offer any help related to HTML code.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this GoDaddy website builder allow you to edit any server side code or embed any javascript on the page?  Using url parameters on the page will require one of these.

Answer (score 1):

you need javascript

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const score= urlParams.get('Score')
console.log(score);
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(score);
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

Something like this will show the score after a div with the id 'div1'